# Create an indicator column if a column contains many string values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
              'col': ['a','a','a','a','b','c','b','a']})

id  col
0   1   a
1   1   a
2   1   a
3   2   a
4   2   b
5   3   c
6   3   b
7   3   a
```

I would like to create an indicator column which will tell me, if an `id` has both "a" and "b" in the `col`

The output should look like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                  'col': ['a','a','a','a','b','c','b','a'], 
'indicator': [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]})


id  col indicator
0   1   a   0
1   1   a   0
2   1   a   0
3   2   a   1
4   2   b   1
5   3   c   1
6   3   b   1
7   3   a   1
```

How can I do that in pandas ?

Comment: I think you should be able to do this using [apply](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-apply-function-usage-examples/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare sets per groups in lambda function in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['indicator'] = (df.groupby('id')['col']
                     .transform(lambda x: set(x) >= {'a','b'})
                     .astype(int))
print (df)
   id col  indicator
0   1   a          0
1   1   a          0
2   1   a          0
3   2   a          1
4   2   b          1
5   3   c          1
6   3   b          1
7   3   a          1
```

Or get same values in both filtered `id` and mapping:

```
both = np.intersect1d(df.loc[df['col'].eq('a'), 'id'],
                      df.loc[df['col'].eq('b'), 'id'])

df['indicator'] = df['id'].isin(both).astype(int)
```

Or mapping compared sets:

```
df['indicator'] = (df['id'].map(df.groupby('id')['col']
                                  .agg(set).ge({'a','b'}).astype(int)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use set operations: [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with  [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset)

```
df['indicator'] = (df.groupby("id")['col']
                     .transform({'a', 'b'}.issubset)
                     .astype(int)
                   )
```

Or:

```
df['indicator'] = (df.groupby("id")['col']
                     .transform(lambda g: int({'a', 'b'}.issubset(g)))
                   )
```

Alternative approach, use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and aggregation with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
s = pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['col']).reindex(columns=['a', 'b']).all(axis=1)

df['indicator'] = df['id'].isin(s.index[s]).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   id col  indicator
0   1   a          0
1   1   a          0
2   1   a          0
3   2   a          1
4   2   b          1
5   3   c          1
6   3   b          1
7   3   a          1
```